# Encountering Issues Deleting a New Authentication Flow in Keycloak 21.0.1 via Console

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-connect

I'm using Keycloak 21.0.1 and encountered an issue while trying to limit the number of sessions per user by creating a new flow. However, the authentication gets completely blocked by this new flow, and when attempting to delete it, I encounter the following problem:

```
Uncaught server error: org.keycloak.models.ModelException: Cannot remove authentication flow, it is currently in use
        at org.keycloak.models.jpa.RealmAdapter.removeAuthenticationFlow(RealmAdapter.java:1605)
        at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmAdapter.removeAuthenticationFlow(RealmAdapter.java:1316)
```

I've tried to locate where it is linked, but it seems no client is associated with this flow. Oddly, it's not marked as "unsed" I'm attaching a screenshot of my flows table for reference. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights, I'd greatly appreciate discussing it.

[image]

Comment: You could export the realm json, and search for references to the flow, maybe you miss some

Comment: @dreamcrash Thank you for your response. I had already checked in the JSON file, and apparently, I hadn't forgotten anything. Eventually, I resolved the issue in a somewhat brute-force manner. I located the flow in the database and deleted it along with all its references in various tables. I didn't fully understand because its ID was indeed linked to a "realm," yet I couldn't see it in the console or the JSON file. If someone knows why I encountered this problem, I would appreciate an explanation. Maybe I'm missing something about authentication flows.